# HTML tag to javascript createElement

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm having a lot of problems trying to write an HTML code in Javascript DOM. This website is my last hope.
I want to convert this HTML tag:

```
<div class="received_msg">
   <div class="received_withd_msg">
      <p>
         <b>Username: </b> Hello everyone!
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have written so far:

```
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.className = 'received_msg';

var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.className = 'received_withd_msg';

var par = document.createElement('p');

var bold = document.createElement('b')

div2.innerHTML += div3.outerHTML;
par.innerHTML += bold.innerHTML + data.username + ' : ' + data.msg;

document.querySelector('#message').append(div2);
document.querySelector('#message').append(par);
```

The above javascript code doesn't print out the HTML code that I want. What's the proper way to do it?

Note that data.username and data.msg are variables referenced in the full code.

Comment: You should be appending, not setting innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be appending the elements you create to their parent elements

```js
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.className = 'received_msg';

var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.className = 'received_withd_msg';

var par = document.createElement('p');

var bold = document.createElement('b');
bold.textContent = "hello";
// var boldTxt = document.createTextNode("Hello");
// bold.appendChild(boldTxt);


var txt = document.createTextNode(" World");

div2.appendChild(div3);
div3.appendChild(par);
par.appendChild(bold);
par.appendChild(txt);

document.body.append(div2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing HTML using vanilla JS might be truly confusing  :) As written above, appending children to parent elements would be easier and better in many ways. Just to complete the whole idea with your case and all the variables:

```js
var data = {username: 'John Doe', msg: 'Hello World!'};
var root = document.querySelector('#root');

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.className = 'received_msg';

var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.className = 'received_withd_msg';

var par = document.createElement('p');
var bold = document.createElement('b');
bold.textContent = `${data.username}: `;
par.appendChild(bold);
var text = document.createTextNode(data.msg);
par.appendChild(text);

div3.appendChild(par);
div2.appendChild(div3);
root.appendChild(div2);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately I can't upvote your answer because I'm new. Yes javascript is so confusing to me, I've never written javascript code until now. Guess I have a lot of learning to do!! thanks for your contribution once again :D

Comment: I'm happy to help, good luck with your learning, it's only difficult in the beginning (no :D)